# select from table where has same value but group by their difference

Tags: mysql, database

For example,I have a table like (I change my example):

```
 +---------------------+
 | starttime   IP      |
 +---------------------+
 | 1          a        |
 | 2          a        |
 | 3          a        |
 | 5          a        |
 | 1          b        |
 | 2          b        |
 | 1          c        |
 | 10         c        |
 +---------------------+
```

Firstly, I group this table by same IP, so I get group a,group b, group c.

In group a, the max stattime is 5, the minimum starttime is 1,5-1=4>2.

in group b, the max is 2,the minimum starttime is 1,2-1=1<2.

in group c, max is 10,minimum is 1,10-1=9>2.

I just want find the group whose max starttime-minimux stattime>2.
I want get the result:

```
 +---------------------+
 | starttime   IP      |
 +---------------------+
 | 1          a        |
 | 2          a        |
 | 3          a        |
 | 5          a        |
 | 1          c        |
 | 10         c        |
 +---------------------+
```

Comment: it is hard to read. can you please format the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  To format a code block or preformatted table, highlight it and use the `{}` editor toolbar button, or `ctl-k`. This results in 4 space indentation as a code block, and provides syntax highlighting as well, based on tags.

Comment: It is not clear what you really want. You are trying to find the maximum starttime - minimum where starttime >= 2 for each IP, but the expected results should return 6 rows for one IP ?

Comment: why not end_time 9 ,10 comes?

Comment: Sorry, I use a wrong word. It is a table. I want to find rows who have same IP.And ( max startime in a group who has same IP)-(minimum starttime in a group who has same IP)>=2. For example, first we group this table by same IP, we have two groups ,the fist group has same IP "a", the second group has same IP "b". In the first group, the max starttime is 5, the minimum stattime is 1. 5-1>=2. But in the second group, the max starttime is 2, the minimum starttime is 1, 2-1<2. Therefore, I just want get the first group.

Comment: OK, very different example now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your table is called **table**:

```
select * from table where "IP" in (select "IP" from table group by "IP" having max(starttime)-min(starttime)>2);
```

This should give you the expected result.

Comment: Great! Please show some love and mark your question as answered.